# What should be the regular expression for password in these conditions?

Tags: regex, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to build the regular expression for password which should accept

```
Alpha, Num, sp characters . - _ @ ! # $ % &
```

I tried with  `@"^([a-zA-Z0-9.*-_@!#$%&]+)$|\b"`
And 
`@"((?=.*\\d)(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[-_@!#$%&\\.]).{6,20})"` but didn't worked. Password is my Model property in MVC application. How should i build the regular expression?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9._@!#$%&-]+$
```

This should work fine for you.Keep `-` at the end or escape it as it defines a range.